# In Perl, how can I can check if an encoding specified in a string is valid?

Tags: perl, file-io, character-encoding

Say, I have a sub that receives two arguments: An encoding specification, and a file path. The sub then uses that information to open a file for reading as shown below, stripped down to its essentials:

```
run({
    encoding => 'UTF-16---LE',
    input_filename => 'test_file.txt',
});

sub run {
    my $args = shift;
    my ($enc, $fn) = @{ $args }{qw(encoding input_filename)};

    my $is_ok = open my $in,
        sprintf('<:encoding(%s)', $args->{encoding}),
        $args->{input_filename}
    ;
}
```

Now, this croaks with:

`Cannot find encoding "UTF-16---LE" at E:\Home\...`

What is the **right** way to ensure that `$args->{encoding}` holds a valid encoding specification before interpolating into the second argument to `open`?

#### Update

The information below is provided in the hope that it will be useful to someone at some point. I am also going to file a [bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=76186).

The documents for [Encode::Alias](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Encode::Alias) do not mention `find_alias` at all. A casual look at the `Encode/Alias.pm` on my Windows system reveals:

```
# Public, encouraged API is exported by default

our @EXPORT =
  qw (
  define_alias
  find_alias
);
```

However, note:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.014;
use Encode::Alias;
say find_alias('UTF-8')->name;
```

yields:

`Use of uninitialized value $find in exists at C:/opt/Perl/lib/Encode/Alias.pm line 25.
Use of uninitialized value $find in hash element at C:/opt/Perl/lib/Encode/Alias.pm line 26.
Use of uninitialized value $find in pattern match (m//) at C:/opt/Perl/lib/Encode/Alias.pm line 31.
Use of uninitialized value $find in lc at C:/opt/Perl/lib/Encode/Alias.pm line 40.
Use of uninitialized value $find in pattern match (m//) at C:/opt/Perl/lib/Encode/Alias.pm line 31.
Use of uninitialized value $find in lc at C:/opt/Perl/lib/Encode/Alias.pm line 40.`

Being 1) lazy, and 2) first to assume I am doing something wrong, I decided to seek others' wisdom.

In any case, [the bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=76186) is due to `find_alias` being exported as a function without checking for that in the code:

```
sub find_alias {
    require Encode;
    my $class = shift;
    my $find  = shift;
    unless ( exists $Alias{$find} ) {
```

If `find_alias` is not invoked as a method, the argument is now in `$class` and `$find` is undefined.

HTH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `find_encoding` function in [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode).  Although, if you want to use it as an `:encoding` layer, [you should also check `perlio_ok`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode#Encoding_via_PerlIO).  It's possible (but rare) for an encoding to exist but not support use with `:encoding`:

```
use Carp qw(croak);
use Encode qw(find_encoding);

sub run {
    my $args = shift;
    my $enc = find_encoding($args->{encoding}) 
      or croak "$args->{encoding} is not a valid encoding";
    $enc->perlio_ok or croak "$args->{encoding} does not support PerlIO";

    my $is_ok = open my $in,
        sprintf('<:encoding(%s)', $enc->name),
        $args->{input_filename}
    ;
}
```

Note: `find_encoding` *does* handle aliases defined by Encode::Alias.

If you don't care about distinguishing between nonexistent encodings and those that don't support `:encoding`, you can just use the `perlio_ok` function:

```
Encode::perlio_ok($args->{encoding}) or croak "$args->{encoding} not supported";
```

Comment: +1 However, note the comment in the source code `# Public, encouraged API is exported by default` followed by `our @EXPORT = qw ( define_alias find_alias );`. In any case, I really like your answer.

Answer (score 5):

`Encode::Alias->find_alias($encoding_name)` returns an object whose `name` attribute is the canonical encoding name on success, and false on failure.

```
$ Encode::Alias->find_alias('UTF-16---LE')
$ Encode::Alias->find_alias('UTF-16 LE')
Encode::Unicode  {
    Parents       Encode::Encoding
    Linear @ISA   Encode::Unicode, Encode::Encoding
    public methods (6) : bootstrap, decode, decode_xs, encode, encode_xs, renew
    private methods (0)
    internals: {
        endian   "v",
        Name   "UTF-16LE",
        size   2,
        ucs2   ""
    }
}
$ Encode::Alias->find_alias('Latin9')
Encode::XS  {
    public methods (9) : cat_decode, decode, encode, mime_name, name, needs_lines, perlio_ok, renew, renewed
    private methods (0)
    internals: 140076283926592
}
$ Encode::Alias->find_alias('UTF-16 LE')->name
UTF-16LE
$ Encode::Alias->find_alias('Latin9')->name
iso-8859-15
```

Comment: The documented solution for this is `find_encoding` in Encode.  See my answer.